# How select multiple Pivot Items using formula in VBA from a Pivot Field

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying use VBA to select all organizations that have a H or N as their fourth character.

I've tried modifying code to select either just H or N and it works. Also this code works, if I reverse the signs by selecting everything that's not H or N.

```
Sub Select_H_and_N_Organizations_View()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PF As PivotField
Dim PI As PivotItem
Dim blnCheck As Boolean

blnCheck = False
Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

If WS.PivotTables.Count > 0 Then

Set PT = WS.PivotTables(1)
PT.ManualUpdate = True

Set PF = PT.PivotFields("Organization")
    For Each PI In PF.PivotItems
        If Mid(PI.Name, 4, 1) = "H" Or Mid(PI.Name, 4, 1) = "N" Then
            blnCheck = True
        End If
    Next PI

    If blnCheck = True Then
Set PF = PT.PivotFields("Organization")
    For Each PI In PF.PivotItems
        If Mid(PI.Name, 4, 1) = "H" Or Mid(PI.Name, 4, 1) = "N" Then
            If PI.Visible = False Then
                PI.Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    Next PI
    For Each PI In PF.PivotItems
        If Mid(PI.Name, 4, 1) <> "H" Or Mid(PI.Name, 4, 1) <> "N" Then
            If PI.Visible = True Then
                PI.Visible = False ''This is where code breaks
            End If
        End If
    Next PI        
    Else
        MsgBox "There are no H or N Organizations available.", vbOKOnly, "Pivot Tables"
    End If

 End If

 PT.ManualUpdate = False
 Set WS = Nothing
 Set PT = Nothing
 Set PF = Nothing
 Set PI = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You checked first, if there is any pivotitem fulfilling your criteria. That is correct, as at least one pivotitem must remain visible.

Then you switched each wanted pivotitem visible.

At last, you want to hide all unwanted. There you just have to change your condition from `Or` to `And`, as otherwise your condition is always met (all would be invisible, and the error occurs at the last pivotitem, as one must remain visible):

```
If Mid(PI.Name, 4, 1) <> "H" And Mid(PI.Name, 4, 1) <> "N" Then
```